# Two dimensional arrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, dimensional

I have a problem with a multiple ArrayList of waypoints.
I have one ship.
A ship has waypoints.

```
public static ArrayList<Waypoint> _waypoints = new ArrayList<>();
```

To add a new waypoint I use

```
 Screen._waypoints.add(
                        new Waypoint(
                           12,20
                        )
                   );
 Screen._waypoints.add(
                        new Waypoint(
                           15,50
                        )
                   );
 Screen._waypoints.add(
                        new Waypoint(
                           17,90
                        )
                   );
```

That means:

1. Ship -> 12,20
2. Ship -> 15,50
3. Ship -> 17,90

I have modified my game and I have added ship types that means every type of ship has a different waypoints.

I modified the waypoints initialization.

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Waypoint>> _waypoints = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Waypoint>>();
```

I want to create this structure:

Ship -> Wood -> Array list of waypoints 
For example I have two types of ship -> Wood and Pirate ship.

Ship -> Wood

1. Ship -> 12,20
2. Ship -> 15,50
3. Ship -> 17,90

Ship -> Pirate

1. Ship -> 12,20
2. Ship -> 15,50
3. Ship -> 17,90

To get the arrayList of the wood I want to use this:

```
waypoints.get("wood");
```

I don't know how to realize it using a two dimensional arrayList of arrayList

Thanks,

Comment: You are looking for a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Though to be honest keeping data in a static manner like this is a code smell. But yea, use a Map instead.

Comment: you can use `Map` and `"wood` and `pirate` will be your keys and `ArrayList<Waypoint>` will be value associated with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

```
public static Map<String, List<Waypoint>> wayPoints = new HashMap<String, List<Waypoint>>();
```

Although, a better approach would be to make your own `ShipType` class and store a list of waypoints on the ship itself. More than likely, you'll have many more properties which are specific to one ship type. This allows you to consolidate those in a single class, making for a much more manageable design.

```
public class ShipType {
    private List<Waypoint> wayPoints = new ArrayList<Waypoint>();
    /* ... */
}
```

Your `Ship`s could then have a `ShipType` instead of "just" the name of their ship type.

```
public class Ship {
    private ShipType type;
    /* ... */
}
```

Then, simply keep a `Map` of your `ShipType`s to properly construct your `Ship`s.

```
public static Map<String, ShipType> ships = new HashMap<String, ShipType>();
// Register ship types
ships.put("wood", new WoodShipType());
// Construct a ship
Ship myShip = new Ship();
myShip.setType(ships.get("wood"));
```

Alternatively, you can use an `enum` with overloaded methods to represent a fixed number of ship types and get rid of that `static` collection altogether.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a `Map`?

```
Map<String, List<WayPoint>> wayPoints = new HashMap<String, List<WayPoint>>();
wayPoints.put("wood", new ArrayList<WayPoint>());
```

And then get the arrayList of the wood by:

```
List<WayPoint> woods = wayPoints.get("wood");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashMap`

```
 public  HashMap<String,ArrayList<Waypoint>> waypoints=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Waypoint>>();

waypoints.put("wood",array list objetct); //insertion

ArrayList<Waypoints> obj=waypoints.get("wood");
```